# How do I disable specific warning/error messages using ALE?

Tags: plugin-ale

I'm currently using ALE to lint my Python code. I'm just curious how to disable specific warning or error messages. I've checked the [GitHub repository's FAQ](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale#5-faq) but I only see an option for disabling linters entirely rather than selected messages (e.g., `line-too-long`). How should I go about this? Thanks.

#### Edit

The specific linter that I want to configure is PyLint. I've tried creating a `.pylintrc` file and adding in messages as per [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341746/how-do-i-disable-a-pylint-warning) but it doesn't seem to be working. What I did is:

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
disable=line-too-long
```

I've also tried using the error codes (e.g., `C0321`) rather than the messages but it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You need to configure the linters in their respective fashions. This can often be done by setting an ALE variable (`:help ale-python-options`) or via a project configuration file. Can you add more specifics (which linter, which rule?)

Comment: Sure, I'll edit in some more details.